# Encrypt with flutter and php, decrypt with php and flutter

Tags: php, node.js, flutter, dart, encryption

I have a chat application created using flutter dart and php mysql as backend and also node js for socket.io

So what i want is if i send a message via flutter dart, i want to encrypt it and send to node js via socket.io which will send it to the other client's flutter app and decrypt it there for the user to see and the node.js will also send it to my php script via json format and stores it in my database via post request. Also I will soon create a website where those messages will be decryted and displayed on the user browser and when i send message using the browser i also want to encrypt it and store in the database so that both flutter and web user can see the decrypted format.

```
const https = require("https");
const http = require("http");
const qs = require("querystring");



function send_to_db(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  var postData = qs.stringify(msg);

  var options = {
    hostname: "*****.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/src/chats/post.php",
    method: "POST",
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Content-Length": postData.length,
    },
    checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
      return undefined;
    },
  };
  var buffer = "";
  var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      buffer += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
      console.log(buffer);
    });
  });

  req.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });

  req.write(postData);
  req.end();
  return buffer;
}
```

Right now is am only encrypting and decrypting using php and am afraid of man in the middle attack since my data can be intercepted from flutter app to node.js before reaching my php side

Please what do I do to achieve this

Comment: How about **signing** the encrypted data to be for sure they got not altered during transport ? If you have access to the data (end to end) I would prefer to run the signature on the original data.

Comment: @MichaelFehr how do i do that

Comment: How about searching for "RSA signature", "ECDSA signature" or "Ed25199" signature with "PHP" and "Flutter". Simple examples for all (cross platform usable): https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/tree/main/RsaSignaturePssString, https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/tree/main/EcSignatureP256Sha256String, https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/tree/main/LibsodiumSignatureDetachedString (disclaimer: I'm the author).